# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SelectedOption' of null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select, react-admin

I am using `react-select` to allow user to multiple select from a list of FEATURE given. My Typescript code which looks like this

`

```
import React from "react";
import { Select } from "react-select";
import { FEATURE } from "routes/models/constants";
interface FeatureSelectProps {
    SelectedOption ?: string;
}
export default class FeatureSelect extends React.Component<FeatureSelectProps, any> {
    handlechange(SelectedOption: any)
    {
        this.setState({SelectedOption});
        if(SelectedOption) 
        {
            console.log(`Selected: ${SelectedOption.label}`);
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { SelectedOption = ' ' } = this.state;  
        return (
            <Select multi={true}
                    name="Features"
                    placeholder="+ Add Feature" 
                    options={FEATURE}
                    value={SelectedOption}
                    onChange={this.handlechange} />
        );
    }
}
```

`

shows this error on loading the page: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SelectedOption' of null`

What is the reason of the same and how to resolve this ?

Comment: Try changing `onChange={this.handlechange}` to `onChange={this.handlechange.bind(this)}`.

Comment: @DorWeid no, it's showing the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that `setState()` is performed before `render()`? Otherwise it‘s probable that SelectedOption is still null when `render()` is called.

Comment: where is initial state of the component?

Comment: @Ashish yes it resolved after declaring the initial state of my component.

Comment: please post your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem was solved with the following edit: 
`

```
export default class FeatureSelect extends React.Component<any, any> {
    state = {
        selectedOption: ""
    };
    handleChange = (selectedOption: any) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        if (selectedOption) {
            console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
        }
    };
    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;
        return (
            <Select
                placeholder="Select Feature(s)"
                multi={true}
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={FEATURE}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

`